# APIGEE API Proxy - How do I prevent a request from hitting the target based on body content

Tags: apigee

I am trying to prevent requests that contain a json payload with a certain attribute value from hitting my target backend.

For example:

```
{"status":"pending"}
```

If the status is "pending", I don't want it to hit my target backend until I see a status of "delivered".

What is the best way to do this?

I have a step in the proxy endpoint preflow that uses a javascript policy to identify the attribute and its value. Now that I know this, how can I prevent the request from hitting the target backend and instead just return a 200 ok to the requester?

Answer (score 0):

As you have the JS to identify the attribute already, now have a policy "Raise-Fault-Attribute" in your preflow after your JS policy.

```
<Step>
    <Condition>(Status is pending) or (Status is null)</Condition>
     <Name>Raise-Fault-Attribute</Name>
</Step>

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <RaiseFault async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="Raise-Fault-Attribute">
<DisplayName>Raise Fault Attribute</DisplayName>
<Properties/>
<FaultResponse>
    <Set>
        <Headers/>
        <Payload contentType="text/xml">
           ....
        </Payload>
        <StatusCode>500</StatusCode>
        <ReasonPhrase>Server Error</ReasonPhrase>
    </Set>
</FaultResponse>
<IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>true</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
</RaiseFault>
```

`

Hope this helps...

Comment: [Fault Handling](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/fundamentals/fault-handling) FYI..